# Possible to check segue from which viewcontroller then do something?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, segue

For example I have 3 views:

- SaveContactView (TableView - Editable)
- DetailedContactView (View - Display only)
- ListContactView (TableView - Display List)

ListContactView contains dynamic records of Customers. Tap on cell will segue to DetailedContactView.

ListContactView contains 'add' button which segue to SaveContactView.

SaveContactView when user save will go to DetailedContactView.

DetailedContactView, user can 'edit' and goes back to SaveContactView

**This is my question:** 
ListContactView to DetailedContactView **OR** SaveContactView to DetailedContactView
On viewDidLoad on DetailedcontactView is it possible to call different methods/functions when he comes from a certain view?

I do not want to create some redundant extra duplicated 'alike' view. So is there any best approach?

Comment: set a property such as a boolean that indicates the source

Comment: They are view controllers, not views.

Comment: Yes my mistake, its viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply apply a check in `viewDidLoad` of your `DetailedContactView` that who is the parent of this view.
If you are using push segue then check the parent view controller of this view controller in `UINavigationControler stack`.

If you are `modally present` this `DetailedContactView` then find the `[self presentingViewController]` and take appropriate action.

Or set a flag from last page to distinguish between parents.

May be this will help you.

Comment: Actually both of them are pretty much in the same stack. So I can't use this answer but thanks for your help. I learnt something today!

Comment: @specialone Yes my brother obviously both will be in same stack but you can find which one is just above your DetailedContactView object in navigation stack and can distinguish. If you want I can give you code. And hopefully I had given you all other options too, possible for distinguish between two ViewControllers. like the one you accepted in above answer. but thanks at least you replied

Comment: Yes, would appreciate if you could provide me the codes so I can understand more about navigation stack. I am still quite new in Objective-C. Thanks for helping out. :)

Comment: By the way, I am using Push and not modal.

Comment: NSArray *array = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
    NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:array.count-2]);          will always print the viewController just above the present view controller.

Comment: Thanks I finally got the stack working to see the viewController just above the present view controller. Just one last question how do I check condition for this? if ([array objectAtIndex:array.count-2] = "ListController") { } Don't seems to work in this way.

Comment: if ([[array objectAtIndex:array.count-2] isKindOfClass:[ListController class]]) {
}

Comment: Your answer is better because I can control methods better for viewDidLoad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to implement `-prepareForSegue:sender:` of SaveContactView and of ListContactView. Cast the destination of the segue to DetailedContactView type and perform custom setup.

```
// SaveContactView
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
                 sender:(id)sender
{
    DetailedContactView *detailedVC = segue.sourceViewController;
    [detailedVC setupForShowingFromSaveView];
}



// ListContactView
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
                 sender:(id)sender
{
    DetailedContactView *detailedVC = segue.sourceViewController;
    [detailedVC setupForShowingFromListView];
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but for the setupforshowingFromList or FromSaved. I am calling [self getCustomer] and [self savedCustomer] on viewDidLoad in their respective viewcontrollers which their methods are also in their respective viewcontrollers. How do I achieve your answer?

Comment: If it is possible, move that code from viewDidLoad to 'setupForShowingFromList'.

Comment: Alright I am going to try and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: When you do you will have some generic setup code in viewDidLoad and more specific code in 'setup' methods.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kelin. It works. I declared my method in the controller.h and did the way you asked when doing segue. Cheers!